# Sin(x+h) Taylor’s series. Is ‘h’ in degrees or radian?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

In the $\sin(x+h)$ Taylor’s series, can $h$ be in degrees or it has to be in radians?

Comment: Being extremely nitpicky,  in maths it is neither - it is unitless. In physics or elsewhere, we do attach a unit to angles, be it degree or radian, which *behaves* as if it were the dimensionless $1$. As in, to compute a side-length ratio in a triangle having one angle of $1.5\,\text{rad}$, we may want to compute the sine of the number $1.5$, strictly speaking not the sine of $1.5\,\text{rad}$. ("But isn't $1.5\,\text{rad}=1.5\,\frac{\text m}{\text m}=1.5$ anyway?" - Well, it depends on how nitpicky you are ;)

Comment: It would help to know what series you're talking about. For example, the (usual) Taylor series for $\sin$ works **only** with radians, as does any formula that involves differentiation/integration of trig functions.

Answer (score 2):

Radians. Generally, whenever in Mathematics done above high school level, angles are always in radians. If degrees are to be used, they will be labelled by $^o$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \sin( \frac{\pi x}{180})$. You can think of $f$ as computing the sine of an angle $x$ which is in degrees rather than radians. The Taylor series for $f$ (centered at $0$) is

\begin{align*}
f(x) &= f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}{2!} x^2 + \frac{f'''(0)}{3!} x^3 + \cdots \\
&= (\pi/180) x - \frac{(\pi/180)^3}{3!} x^3 + \frac{(\pi/180)^5}{5!} x^5 - \cdots.
\end{align*}

This is of course the same result you would obtain by plugging $u = \pi x/ 180$ into the series
$$
\sin(u) = u - \frac{u^3}{3!} + \frac{u^5}{5!} - \cdots.
$$

Note that you can't compute the sine of a 30 degree angle by just plugging the number 30 into the standard Taylor series for sine. You must first convert to radians.

Answer (score 0):

It can be either, but it *must* be the same as $x$.

As Ishan Deo said, it is generally going to be radians if you're in a college course.